# Update MySQL table based on results for joining to tables

Tags: mysql, email, sql-update, subquery, left-join

I have three tables, emails, person_details and data_providers.  Basically all of my users id, email, and current assigned data_providers_id are stored in the emails table.

The second table, person_details contains demographic information collected by multiple data providers, each row identified by an emails_id that is relational to the emails.id data_providers_id that is relational to the third table data_providers.id

The third table, data_providers contains each of my data providers id, name, and precedence.

Basically, a users information could be collected from multiple sources, and I need to `UPDATE emails set data_providers_id =` based on a select that would JOIN the person_details table and the data_providers table sorting by data_providers.precedence DESC then person_details.import_date ASC and use the first value (highest precedence, then oldest import_date).

I was trying to build the query, but my subquery is returning more than one row.  This query is a little over my head, hoping someone more experienced with complex queries might be able to point me in the right direction.

```
UPDATE emails 
SET emails.data_providers_id = 
    SELECT person_details.data_providers_id 
    FROM person_details 
    LEFT JOIN data_providers ON person_details.data_providers_id = data_providers.id
    ORDER BY data_providers.percent_payout ASC, person_details.import_date ASC ;
```

Here are some details about the three tables if this helps.  Any guidance would be MUCH appreciated.  Thanks in advance :)

emails table:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| data_providers_id | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| email             | varchar(255)        | NO   | UNI | NULL                |                |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

person_details:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field             | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| emails_id         | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| data_providers_id | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| fname             | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| lname             | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| address_line1     | text                | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| address_line2     | text                | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| city              | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| state             | varchar(2)          | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| zip5              | varchar(5)          | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| zip4              | varchar(4)          | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| home_phone        | varchar(10)         | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| mobile_phone      | varchar(10)         | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| work_phone        | varchar(10)         | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| dob               | date                | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| gender            | varchar(1)          | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| ip_address        | varchar(15)         | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| source            | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| optin_datetime    | datetime            | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
| import_date       | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
+-------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

data_providers table:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | tinyint(3) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| precedence      | int(2)              | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: In the absence of a WHERE... IS NULL statement, LEFT JOINs on UPDATES are a bit weird

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the heads up.  Luckily on this table all of the columns required by the query are NOT NULL.

Comment: hm - you're missing the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a `SELECT` as an expression you have to put it in parentheses. And to get the first value, use `LIMIT 1`:

```
UPDATE emails 
SET emails.data_providers_id = (
    SELECT person_details.data_providers_id 
    FROM person_details 
    LEFT JOIN data_providers ON person_details.data_providers_id = data_providers.id
    WHERE person_details.emails_id = emails.id
    ORDER BY data_providers.percent_payout ASC, person_details.import_date ASC
    LIMIT 1) ;
```

Comment: your select works perfectly in that it returns a single row, however it is going to update EVERY record in the emails table with the same single row result.  I need to update each row of the  emails table independently based on emails.id matching person_details.emails_id.

Comment: I've changed the answer to use a correlated subquery.

Comment: Sorry, looking back at the question that really was not clear at all.  Thank you so much for your help, greatly appreciated!  It looks so simple now that you laid it out, not sure why I kept tripping up over this query.